# Azure ARM Template Deployment in existing Availability Set

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-availability-set

From the template below how do I add it to an existing Availability Set(Same resource group). I can't do this after VM creation so I need to do it here.

Getting error as

> The Availability Set
>   '/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Com
>   pute/availabilitySets/XXXXXXX' cannot be found.

However it is available on portal. I can deploy VM manually.

```
{
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        SOME MORE PARAMETERS
        "AvSet":{
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        },

    },
    "variables": {
        "ExtensionLink": "[concat(parameters('containerUrl'),'/domainjoin_extension.json')]",
        "subnetRef": "[resourceId(parameters('existingVnetResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('existingVnetName'),  parameters('existingSubnetName'))]",

    },
    "resources": [{
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "tags": "[parameters('tagValues')]",
            "properties": {
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
                    "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                    "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
                },
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "imageReference": {
                        "publisher": "[parameters('publisher')]",
                        "offer": "[parameters('offer')]",
                        "sku": "[parameters('OSVersion')]",
                        "version": "latest"
                    },
                    "osDisk": {
                        "createOption": "fromImage",
                        "diskSizeGB": "[parameters('diskSizeGB')]",
                        "managedDisk": {
                            "storageAccountType": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
                        },
                        "name": "[parameters('osDiskName')]"
                    }

                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [{
                        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
                    }]
                },

                "diagnosticsProfile": {
                    "bootDiagnostics": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "storageUri": "[reference(resourceId(parameters('existingStorageRgName'), 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('existingDiagnosticsStorageAccountName')), '2015-06-15').primaryEndpoints['blob']]"
                    }
                },
                "AvailabilitySet" : {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets', parameters('AvSet'))]"
                },
            },

            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]",

            ]
        },

        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaceName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "tags": "[parameters('tagValues')]",
            "properties": {

                "ipConfigurations": [{
                    "name": "ipconfig1",
                    "properties": {
                        "subnet": {
                            "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                        },
                        "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
            "name": "linked1",
            "condition": "[equals(parameters('extensionCreateorNot'),'yes')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                    "uri": "[variables('ExtensionLink')]",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "virtualMachineName": {
                        "value": "[string(parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
                    },
                    "domainJoinUserName": {
                        "value": "[string(parameters('domainJoinUserName'))]"
                    },
                    "domainJoinUserPassword": {
                        "value": "[string(parameters('domainJoinUserPassword'))]"
                    },
                    "domainFQDN": {
                        "value": "[string(parameters('domainFQDN'))]"
                    },
                    "ouPath": {
                        "value": "[string(parameters('ouPath'))]"
                    }

                }

            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "linked2",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"

            ]
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
            "name": "linked2",
            "condition": "[equals(parameters('dataDisksattachornot'),'yes')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                    "uri": "[variables('attachDataDiskExtensionLink')]",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "virtualMachineName": {
                        "value": "[string(parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
                    },
                    "sizeOfDataDisksInGB": {
                        "value": "[array(parameters('sizeOfDataDisksInGB'))]"
                    },
                    "tagValues": {
                        "value": "[parameters('tagValues')]"
                    }
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "adminUsername": {
            "type": "String",
            "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
        },
        "virtualMachineName": {
            "type": "String",
            "value": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]"
        },
        "networkInterface": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[reference(concat(parameters('networkInterfaceName'))).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress]"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to add vm to existing availabilty set - you have to give it its resourceId, that is. add the following parameter to vm properties:

```
"availabilitySet": {
    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets', 'existing_availability_set_name')]"
},
```

example:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-2-vms-loadbalancer-natrules/azuredeploy.json#L264

Comment: whats the question in that case

Comment: Question is i have verified on azure portal. My availability set exist there. I can deploy VM manually with AVSet. However from shared ARM it gives me error as AVSet is not available.

Comment: means its on a different region or you constructed the resource id improperly

Comment: No, AVSet is in same region and same resource Group. I am not sure whats wrong with my template

Comment: unless you can show a repro, this is just your opinion. I know this is how it works. and it does. so you have a mistake somewhere

Comment: I have shared template in question

Comment: template is fine, like i told you, check everything. something is off

Comment: To find SOMETHING, I have posted question here.I am not able to check what is missing

Comment: I've told you what can be wrong. region or name. template is fine

Comment: Just to update here, Location of resource group and availability set is different

Comment: exactly, your vm is using resource group location, change vm location to match availability set location.

Comment: I am not adding AVSet to VM, I trying to creating VM with AvSet from different location

Comment: you cant do that (by definition). availability sets offer rack level distribution of virtual machies. vm in one region and vm in another region cannot be in the same rack, because they are in different datacenters, you need to look at availability zones